# How do you foreach a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, foreach

JS6 has added forEach functionality to arrays and Maps. But, that seem have forgotten to do it for the dictionaries. I want to foreach a dictionary. What do I miss? What I am supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean with dictionary? I know Map, Set, Array, Object but whats a dictionary?

Comment: JavaScript doesnt have a native dictionary.

Comment: What difference do you make between a `Map`and a `dictionary`? Anyway Javascript uses `Map` (and `Object`).

Comment: `Object.keys` and `Object.values`.

Comment: As an aside, there's no such thing as "JS6". There's "ES6", better known by its official title ES2015. See [Mozilla's documentation on "JavaScript"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript), versioning of which ended in 2010.

Comment: I always believed that `{}` is a synonym of a dictionary. It is in python, at least. I fail to see the difference.

Comment: @zzzzBov That is fine. But, I often want the both. Map.forEach gives you the iterator of (key, value). I want the same for the `{}`.

Comment: @LittleAlien, so write a function that does what you want. It's a one-liner: `function each(obj, fn) { Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => fn(key, obj[key])); }`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a discussion about that: [ES6 iteration over object values](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-iteration-over-object-values)

And one of the possibilities how you do it with a helper function:

```
function* entries(obj) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    yield [key, obj[key]];
  }  
}

for (let [key, value] of entries(myObj)) {
  // do something with key|value
}
```

For ES7 [Object.values / Object.entries](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) and [Object.enumerableEntries](https://github.com/leobalter/object-enumerables) are proposed.

Answer (score 3):

EcmaScript 2017 introduced `Object.entries`. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Output:

> a: somestring
>   b: 42

Answer (score 1):

[zzzzBov gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379972/how-do-you-foreach-a-dictionary#comment64170433_38379972) the best answer

```
function each(obj, fn) { Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => fn(key, obj[key])); }
```

It fits the `map` purpose as well

```
Object.prototype.map = function(f) { return Object.keys(this).map(key => f(this[key], key)); }
```